# React Native - Horizontal flatlist inside horizontal flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

How to make a horizontal list nested in a horizontal list?

It is necessary that the first list has horizontal positioning and the scrolling is disabled (it will be implemented by clicking through `scrollTo()`), and the second one should be a horizontal list with `pagingEnabled`

[My example code](https://snack.expo.dev/2Ny9TbWRa)

Comment: All relevant code should be posted in the question, not in an external source.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example and I too am unsure why the nested list does not appear horizontal using the `horizontal` prop. As a workaround I used the numColumns parameter in the nested list which I think does the functionality you're looking for: https://snack.expo.dev/szFpr_XfP

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, Dimensions, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    { type: 'row', text: 'row 1'},
    { type: 'row', text: 'row 2'},
    { type: 'list', data: ['Apple', 'Banna', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Pineapple']},
    { type: 'row', text: 'row 3'},
    { type: 'row', text: 'row 4'},
    { type: 'row', text: 'row 5'},
    { type: 'list', data: ['Bike', 'Car', 'Train', 'Plane', 'Boat', 'Rocket']},
    { type: 'row', text: 'row 6'},
    { type: 'row', text: 'row 7'},
    { type: 'row', text: 'row 8'},
  ];

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      renderItem={({item}) => {
        if (item.type === 'row') {
          return (
            <View style={{width: width, height: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Text>{item.text}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <FlatList
              data={item.data}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              numColumns={item.data.length}
              scrollEnabled={false}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                  <View style={{width: width, height: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                  </View>
                )
              }
            />
          );
        }
      }}
      horizontal
      pagingEnabled
    />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, but now a different problem. My parent `FlatList` should not scroll `scrollEnabled={false}`, but the child should. As I understand it, due to the fact that the parent has `scrollEnabled={false}`, the scrolling does not work for the child `FlatList` either. How to fix this problem?